# IE8 won't submit form on ENTER in Windows 7 using https protocol, but will on Vista, XP, etc

Tags: html, forms, windows-7, internet-explorer-8

This is a weird one, and unfortunately I can't test it. At my company we are on Vista now and are not slated to get our Win 7 machines for another few weeks, but a client is complaining about it now.

Basically, we have a form with username/password inputs and a submit button. Normal procedure is to enter your data and hit ENTER, bingo, off and running. This works everywhere and under all conditions EXCEPT in IE8 on Windows 7 when the https secure protocol is used.

I've read through the "Related Questions" offered when I created the title for this question (it's not the multiple forms issue, not the display:none issue, etc., because our page doesn't do any of that), and I've searched the Web, but as I have no Win 7 box right now and am under deadline pressure here, I beg your indulgence and turn to all you for any light you may shed on this issue at all.

Are there any security settings in IE8 or Win 7 that would prevent forms from submitting through ENTER key in IE8 on Win 7 using https? Anyone have any ideas at all? Please don't be afraid to speculate, I will not mark you down. This is kind of an emergency and I'm looking for any insights you may have. Thanks in advance.

Comment: code sample would provide the most accurate responses :)

Comment: speculating: does it happen to be a .net page with more than one element on the page with a postback event attached?

Comment: Do you have a submit button in your form?

Comment: @jaywon: D'oh! Good point. I was in a rush trying to finish up my Friday avalanche and didn't think to do that. I won't be back in the office until Monday, but I will provide one then if David's answer below doesn't cure the problem.
@DA: Thanks, but it's a JSP page with only the one submit button.
@Pekka: Yes, thanks. As I noted in the first sentence of my 2nd paragraph, there are two inputs and one submit button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the code it's hard to diagnose.  Try adding this to your page and seeing if it improves consistency.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I won't get to put this into action until Monday, so I sincerely hope to award you the checkmark then.

Comment: Brilliant! Worked like a champ. Thanks again, David. You rock!